# Trying to get property of non-object when display value of json response in Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, json, laravel, guzzle

i try to display the value of json response . Its work well when I dd   `@php dd( $user->irel__com_access_level->ID); @endphp` inside blade view but when i try to display at table it return error which is

> Trying to get property of non-object

My code display in table

```
     @foreach($content as $user)
      <td>{{ $user->irel__com_access_level->ID }}</td>
     @endforeach
```

Here is my json response ....i want to display ID which is inside irel__com_access_level

```
{
    "data": [
        {

        {
            "ID": "banana",
            "PWD": "W6ph5Mm5Pz8GgiULbPgzG37mj9g=",
            "NICK_NAME": "BANANA NANA NA",
            "PWD_INVALID_HIT": "0",
            "PWD_CREATE_DT": "2019/09/06 16:44:40",
            "INSTITUTION_ID": "C01",
            "ACL_ID": "L03",
            "LOGIN_DT": "                   ",
            "LOGIN_STS_ID": "N",
            "STS_ID": "C03",
            "TYPE_ID": "U00",
            "UPD_ID": "asmidah",
            "UPD_DT": "2019/09/06 16:44:40",
            "EMAIL_ID": "banana@gmail.com",
            "PHONE_NO_ID": "0",
            "HP_ID": "0101234567               ",
            "CRT_DATE_DELETED": "2019/09/06 16:44:40",
            "irel__com_access_level": {
                "ID": "L03",       // i want to display this
                "DESCRIPTION": "2NDLEVEL",
                "IS_CREATE": "N",
                "IS_READ": "Y",
                "IS_UPDATE": "Y",
                "IS_DELETE": "N",
                "STS_ID": "R01",
                "UPD_ID": "shukrimb",
                "UPD_DT": "2012/09/13 13:28:25"
           }
```

my controller

```
 private $client;

    public function __construct(){


        $this->client = new Client(['base_uri' => 'http://172.19.52.6/api/configuration/getUserIndex']);

    }

    public function index()
    {

        $response =  $this->client->get('getUserIndex');
         $content = json_decode($response->getBody());

         return view('configuration.comuserprofiles.ComUserProfilesList', ['content' => $content->data]);
```

i want to display ID which is inside irel__com_access_level in json response

Comment: As error states either $user or $irel__com_access_level is not object and you are trying to get the properties. You can check the variable type using var_dum($user) and var_dump($user->irel__com_access_level)

Comment: yea its working fine when i var_dump but when i try to display in table it return error Trying to get property of non-object when display value of json response

Comment: try this in your loop `@if (empty($user->irel__com_access_level)) dd($user) @endif`

Comment: still same sir...

Comment: what is it return ?

Comment: Trying to get property of non-object when display value of json response

Comment: no, i mean you need to put it before `<td>{{ $user->irel__com_access_level->ID }}</td>` or just change this code to `@if (empty($user->irel__com_access_level)) dd($user) @endif`

Comment: syntax error sir

Comment: put a dd($content) before returning view. And show what is the content you get

Comment: This `"data": [
        {

        {...` is strange in your json response.. Why two opening braces {{ ?

Comment: my bad @porloscerrosΨ i copy certain data till i forgot to check

Comment: @AmalSR 2 it return array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just already solved this answer by adding isset

```
 <td>    @if(isset($user->irel__com_access_level))


         @if(trim($user->ACL_ID) == trim($user->irel__com_access_level->ID))
              {{ $user->irel__com_access_level->DESCRIPTION }}   
         @endif

        @endif

     </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 return view('configuration.comuserprofiles.ComUserProfilesList', ['content' => $content->data->first()]);
```

or

```
 return view('configuration.comuserprofiles.ComUserProfilesList', ['content' => $content->data()->first()]);
```

Comment: return error which is Call to undefined method stdClass::data()

Comment: 'content' => $content->data->first() use this